# checkbox not get checked according to list values in android

Tags: android, arraylist

Sorry for my bad English,
I am individually getting array list value to the checkboxes. (Actually, these are the weekdays that are coming from the activity). but the problem is checkbox only set the first position value to checkbox. Please let me know what's wrong in my code.

Below is the Code Snippet

Let Say this is the list value:

**[Monday, Tuesday, Sunday]**

This is the class that i passing the list

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {

            switch (myList.get(i)){

                case "Monday":
                    cbMon.setChecked(true);
                    break;

                case "Tuesday" :
                    cbTue.setChecked(true);
                    break;

                case "Wednesday":
                    cbWed.setChecked(true);
                    break;

                case "Thursday":
                    cbThurs.setChecked(true);
                    break;

                case "Friday":
                    cbFri.setChecked(true);
                    break;

                case "Saturday":
                    cbSat.setChecked(true);
                    break;

                case "Sunday":
                    cbSun.setChecked(true);
                    break;

                default:

                    break;

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

use this structure no need to do it in hardcode way

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {

        switch (myList.get(i)){

            case "Monday":
                cbMon.setChecked(true);
                break;

            case "Tuesday" :
                cbTue.setChecked(true);
                break;

            case "Sunday":
                cbSun.setChecked(true);
                break;

            default:break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: show the elements of array what you are getting @AshishKumar

Comment: use this code and show me arraylist value from logat problem dosen't make any sense after this  @AshishKumar

Comment: for (String element : myList) {
           Log.e("ELEMENT",element); 
        }

Comment: separate dayname and date use only dayname how do you get these values ? craeting by own @AshishKumar

Comment: yes sir, i am passing the list from one activity to other and then set it to the checkboxes

Comment: still there are many factor for this problem..how do you pass the data..how do you getting these data @AshishKumar

Comment: i am posting my two activity, where these things happen

Comment: do you save sunday,monday,true format of string to getter setter of days your logcat menssion date and days combined before @AshishKumar

Comment: sir its a logcat time and date.

Comment: sir please mention that log again in comment its deleted @AshishKumar

Comment: you are getting combined string of day and date E/ELEMENT: Friday 2019-09-18 you just have to separate day to use it @AshishKumar

Comment: E/ELEMENT: Monday
 E/ELEMENT:  Tuesday
 E/ELEMENT:  Wednesday

Comment: oh really sorry !..my bad @AshishKumar

Answer (score 0):

You don't need

> for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)

Answer (score 0):

Try using OR (||) in your if() statement.

```
if(a==b  || a==c || b==c)
        {
            //Your action
        }
```

or Better use switch cases,

```
switch(position) {
  case 0:
    ...
    break;
  case 1:
    ...
    break;
  default:
    ...

}
```